# Javascript inheritance: is my solution correct?

Tags: javascript, extension-methods

I have been developing Javascript for few months, and, as a former Java developer, needed a simple way to perform class inheritance.

My needs are:

- having private members not accessible (encapsulation),
- to make inheritance simple,
- to avoid 'new' keywords bugs,
- to let the superclass methods accessible using the this.super property.

The purpose of this request is to indicate me if the solution I developped should be applied into my project or if there are some misbehaviour risks by using it, and if you have remarks on how to enhance it.

My code is below, thank you for your reviews.

```
/**
* Allows to retrieve the global object (used to test if the 'new' keyword is needed)
*/
function getGlobal(){
    return (function(){
            return this;
    }).call(null);
}

if (typeof Object.extend !== 'function') {
    Object.extend = function (object, superClassConstructor, superConstructorArgs) {
        //Inherits from the super object
        superClassConstructor.apply(object, superConstructorArgs);

        //make this.super allow to access to inherited object original functions
        object.super = {};
        for (var property in object){
            object.super[property] = object[property];
        }
    };
}
//The superclass
function SuperClass(options){
    //Make sure we will not alter global object
    if (this === getGlobal()){ 
        throw new Error("Constructor cannot be called as a function (new keyword should not be omitted)");
    }
    //Use of jshashtable-2.1:
    var attributes = new Hashtable();

    for (var key in options){
        attributes.put(key, options[key]);
    }

    this.setValue = function(key, value){
        if(value != null){
            attributes.put(key, value);
        }
        else{
            attributes.remove(key);
        }
    };

    this.getValue = function(key){
        return attributes.get(key);
    };
}

/**
* Inheriting class
*/
function ProjectModel(projectId) {
    //Make sure we will not alter global object
    if (this === getGlobal()){ 
        throw new Error("Constructor cannot be called as a function (new keyword should not be omitted)");
    }
    //extends SuperClass
    Object.extend(this, SuperClass, [{
                                    id:projectId,
                                    'one':1,
                                    'two':"2"
                                    }]);

    this.myType = "ProjectNumber";
    //Overriding a function
    this.getValue = function(key){
        return this.myType + ":" + this.super.getValue(key);
    };
}

var project = new ProjectModel(123);
alert(project.getValue('one')); //this displays 'ProjectNumber:123'
```

Comment: I do not agree: I do not try to do like Java, I try to do OOP. This means encapsulation and encapsulation is not possible without private attributes.

Comment: To create private attributes/methods in JavaScript, just use local variables in the constructor; they will be bound in the public methods of the object, without being exposed to other objects. `/*constructor*/ function counter() { var cnt=0; this.getNext()={return cnt++;};}`

Comment: Have you looked at the way existing JavaScript libraries do this? E.g. Look at [dojo.declare](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/declare.html). Or consider simply consider using it.

Comment: Thank you ammoQ, I already knew this: my goal here was to allow inheritance from a class that has private attributes and to add new private attributes to the subclass (without seeing superclass' private attributes)

Comment: @MarkJ: yes, it seems that it is something like dojo.declare that I was trying to do. Thank you for this, I will try it.

Comment: @lauhub you don't need "private" that's not what encapsulation is about.

Comment: @Raynos: I do know what I need and, as far as I know, using "private" or not-accessible members is a way to deal with encapsulation.

Comment: @lauhub but you don't need "privates". They are slow, ugly and a pain in the ass. If you going to use "privates" then give up on OO and use closures everywhere. State bound in closures is actually quite elegant but you shouldn't be emulating OO using it. closures (functional programming) and inheritance (OO programming) are parallel constructs pick one or the other because any combination of the two is ugly

Comment: @Raynos: thank you but I do not agree with this.

Comment: Encapsulation is quite possible without private variables.  The most basic point of encapsulation is that you make it possible to work with an object without knowing anything about its innards.  Not necessarily that the innards are hidden behind some kind of codewall.  We're all adults here, and should be able to follow a simple guideline like "don't mess with properties directly; call functions that mess with the properties for you".  Python, Perl, JS, etc get by just fine without private properties.  That you see some need for them is evidence of a C++ or Java mindset.

Comment: @cHao: I work with non IT engineers since 10 years (mechanical engineers, scientific researchers) who modify or code some stuffs. And all I have to say is, although they are very efficient into their fields, they are not able to follow some IT rules only because they are more interested into their fields than in IT. My job is to support them. My question was: "is my code correct and how to enhance it ?", it was not "what is your opinion about software development ?" Thank you to all the people who understand that.

Comment: If they can't follow a simple rule, then they have no business touching code.  Period.  They wouldn't tolerate you coming in and scribbling on their plans/graphs/whatever they use; if your work is any less worthy of respect, crap like this is why. And the answer to your question is "No, because the very idea is flawed.  Javascript does not have classes.  It does not have private variables. It is not Java, and you can not turn it into Java, because the two languages are fundamentally different.  The more you try, the more gotchas you'll run into. That way lies madness. You've been warned."

Comment: @cHao: about business of people: you are not the one who decides about who do what. About private variable etc: a link (from D. Crockford, I think you know him as you know javascript): [link](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: Know him?  Yes.  Take every word he says as gospel?  Not on your life.  Everything he and anyone else says should be evaluated on its own merits.  And in this case, private variables are rather incompatible with the idea of prototypal inheritance (which is another of his big ones, and one i can agree with).  Even he has said "I now see my early attempts to support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake" ([link](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html), at the bottom of the page).

Comment: No need to follow your link: I already did it. And evaluated myself what is good for me without imposing it to anyone else.

Comment: "Without imposing it to anyone else", you say?  Did you forget those engineers and researchers you feel the need to treat like spoiled brats who'll destroy anything that isn't bolted down and locked up?  They are allegedly the whole reason for this monstrosity, after all...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to try writing code in one language as if it were a different language.

Don't fight your tool; use it as it was designed. JavaScript has prototype-based OO rather than class-based OO, so use it like that.

Read "Javascript - the Good Parts" and learn to write actually good JavaScript rather than "Java in JavaScript" (for which other developers working with your code will hate and/or mock you).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But OOP means encapsulation and encapsulation means nothing without private attributes.

I do not fight, I just currently think that it is possible to have a simple way to do this without falling into traps (none of the solutions I found was simple nor efficient enough)

Comment: @lauhub so you've asserted, twice. But no, encapsulation does *not* mean private variables, as any programmer in Python (for example) will tell you. Again, please drop the Java mindset when you're not using Java.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: encapsulation means information hiding. From what I know from Python, a variable is private only if it is prefixed with __.
Problem: it is not possible always to trust developpers will not do forbidden access to private members. This is an observation from my experience programming with other languages (actually I did not write a line of Java code since 6 years).

Comment: @lauhub: You're right that encapsulation is important, and your code seems to use the generally accepted way to implement it in JavaScript.

Comment: `it is not possible always to trust developpers` -- then NO amount of encapsulation is sufficient!

Comment: @greengit: it is not sufficient, it is a higher security level. And this is not the subject of this topic.

Comment: @lauhub "it is not possible always to trust developpers" Fire your developers. Stop writing ugly ass code to deal with incompetent team mates. We really need to get over this problem, the solution is not becoming a turtle fortress in your code.

Comment: @raynos: thank you for my ugly ass code. And you will learn that, sometimes, developpers are customers that you cannot fire.

Actually, I decided to fire myself from these kind of projects, but I still have to eat, this is my human condition ;)

Comment: @lauhub: mind you, in many languages that support private members, it is trivial to access them anyway, via reflection.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic: I know reflection, but I also know that developpers who ignore trivial encapsulation rules also ignore what reflection is. So this is a protection shield.

Comment: @lauhub: Are they also ignorant enough to replace keywords "private" with "public"? The bottom line is: you really can't use language features to fix broken development process; if someone doesn't like encapsulation, they will break it. Just don't sweat over things like that.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic: I can use language feature because I furnish an API to some users who will not be able to break my encapsulation. And I also can control if a member is private or not with code control tools.

Comment: @lauhub why does it matter if they break encapsulation. If _they_ break it, then it's _their_ problem. Not yours

Comment: "it is not possible always to trust developpers" A bit of a tangent, but this mindset is something that has always bugged me about Java. The entire language is infused with the sense that you are being talked down to, versus languages like Python that give you a sense of being respected.

Comment: @jhocking: my need is not to have a discussion about which is the best programming language and why. My need is to prevent _javascript_ developpers (who are human) to make errors by simple and easy to apply coding rules.

Comment: @lauhub prevent developers from making errors is really easy. Write unit tests, make sure unit tests pass before you commit any code.

Comment: @Raynos: _prevent developers from making errors is really easy_ well, in a real world this kind of assertion is not always true, especially when you have to learn programmers what is a unit test. Actually my need was not philosophy nor orthodoxy rules about software development as anyone here has a different philosophy.

Comment: @lauhub you don't have unit tests? :( I feel sorry for you and your team. Maybe you should get a better job

Answer (score 6):

No, it's wrong. JavaScript inheritance is really easy.

```
var SomeKlass = {
  ...
};

var someInstance = Object.create(SomeKlass);
```

For a more complete example / conversion of your code see [the following example](http://jsfiddle.net/vKTnc/4/)

> to make inheritance simple,

Can't be any simpler, to inherit any object call `Object.create` on it.

> to avoid 'new' keywords bugs,

You don't use `new` anymore so that problem dissappeared

> to let the superclass methods accessible using the this.super property.

Emulating `super` with elegant syntax is a [seriously non trivial problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8032566/419970)

The best mechanism I've seen is function replacement with either setting `this.$super` to a sensible value before and after or recompiling the function to reference a super object. Both of those solutions are ugly, I'd recommend just referencing the super object directly by name.

> having private members not accessible (encapsulation),

You can't do non accessible private members in JavaScript using prototypical OO. You can use closures, but that's not prototypical OO and that does not work with prototypical OO.

I recommend you use pseudo internal properties prefixed with `_` and shoot any developer who uses it.

Alternatively you can use namespaces. [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9QmPf/4/).

```
var SuperClass = (function () {
    // Name shim : https://gist.github.com/1344853
    var privates = Name();

    return {
        constructor: function (options) {
            privates(this).attributes = options;
        },
        setValue: function (key, value) {
            if (value) {
                privates(this).attributes[key] = value;    
            } else {
                delete privates(this).attributes[key];
            }
        },
        getValue: function (key) {
            return privates(this).attributes[key];
        }
    };
})();


// Object.make : https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.make
var ProjectModel = Object.make(SuperClass, {
    constructor: function (projectId) {
        SuperClass.constructor.call(this, {
            id: projectId,
            one: 1,
            two: "2"  
        });
        this.myType = "ProjectModel";
    },
    getValue: function (key) {
        return this.myType + ":" + SuperClass.getValue.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

var project = Object.create(ProjectModel);
project.constructor(123);
alert(project.getValue('one')); //this displays 'ProjectNumber:123'
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution: I already tried it and it does not fulfill my first need (private members). You are out of the scope.

Comment: @lauhub what? `Name` fulfills private members in a very elegant way and it actually works with prototypical OO

Comment: Sorry, I did not have noticed you had changed your code. Your first version did not use Name and I agree that it is an elegant way to do that.

Thank you

Comment: I have only a remark: if I need to create a private member, I have to write `privates(this).myVariable`.

This is not as simple as `var myVariable` and I usually declare more that a single private member.

Comment: I would cache privates, so `var _ = privates(this)` and then `_.myVariable = ...` so it's actually one less character. However you get the massive advantage of people to access private variables outside of the constructor scope as long as you have a reference to `privates`

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account remarks and suggestions, here is an enhanced version of my initial code: it works and fulfills my needs.

```
/**
* Allows to retrieve the global object
*/
function getGlobal(){
    return (function(){
            return this;
    }).call(null);
}
function getFunctionName(fonction){
    var nom = fonction.toString();
    nom = nom.substr('function '.length);
    nom = nom.substr(0, nom.indexOf('('));
    return nom;
}    
if (typeof Object.extend !== 'function') {
    Object.extend = function (object, objectConstructor, superClassConstructor, superConstructorArgs) {
        //To stop if new keyword was not used
        if (object === getGlobal()){  
            throw new Error("Constructor should always be called with new keyword.");
        }
        //Check arguments:
        if(objectConstructor === undefined){throw new Error("Missing argument: objectConstructor");} 
        if(superClassConstructor === undefined){throw new Error("Missing argument: superClassConstructor");} 
        if(superConstructorArgs === undefined){throw new Error("Missing argument: superConstructorArgs");} 

        //Calls super class' constructor, apply it to new object:
        superClassConstructor.apply(object, superConstructorArgs);

        //Create a super class "mirror" object
        var superProperties = {};
        //At this point, the new object will only have super object properties
        //Copies each property:
        for (var property in object){
            superProperties[property] = object[property];
        }
        //Set it to new object:
        object.super = superProperties;

        //put super class name into a property
        if(object.super.className === undefined){
            object.super.className = getFunctionName(superClassConstructor);
        }
        //Set className for object
        var className = getFunctionName(objectConstructor);
        object.className = className;
        //Set constructor for object
        object.constructor = objectConstructor;
    };
}
//The superclass
function SuperClass(options){
    //Inherits from object:
    Object.extend(this, arguments.callee, Object, [{}]);

    //Use of jshashtable-2.1:
    var attributes = new Hashtable();

    for (var key in options){
        attributes.put(key, options[key]);
    }

    this.setValue = function(key, value){
        if(value != null){
            attributes.put(key, value);
        }
        else{
            attributes.remove(key);
        }
    };

    this.getValue = function(key){
        return attributes.get(key);
    };
}

/**
* Inheriting class
*/
function ProjectModel(projectId) {
    //extends SuperClass
    Object.extend(this, arguments.callee, SuperClass, [{
                                    id:projectId,
                                    'one':1,
                                    'two':"2"
                                    }]);

    this.myType = "ProjectNumber";
    //Overriding a function
    this.getValue = function(key){
        return this.myType + ":" + this.super.getValue(key);
    };
}

var project = new ProjectModel(123);
alert(project.getValue('one'));
//At this point, project will have:
// - a className property set to "ProjectModel"
// - a super property which will contain:
// --> className set to "SuperClass"
// --> setValue and getValue functions from SuperClass
// --> a super property set to Object parent class 
//     (with a className property set to "Object")
```

Comment: Actually, the first thing I found that does not work with this is instanceof function: it does not work with super classes. A work around is to do SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass() after SubClass declaration.